# IntelliJ Idea two APK files

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apk

I am using IntelliJ Idea for Android development. I want to release the app for beta testing but after building the app there are two apk's one inside app folder and another inside the app folder/bin directory both have different sizes, one inside the bin folder in bigger than the one inside the app folder.

**My Question**

1. Why there are two apks?
2. Why both the apk's have different sizes?
3. Which one should be used for beta distribution by email?

Comment: Please specify you IDEA version. Are there any custom Artifacts for producing the APK files that you've configured?

Comment: Idea Version 11.1.3. What do you mean by "custom Artifacts"?

Comment: In IDEA 12 it's possible to configure Artifacts for Android modules. IDEA 11 by default builds only one apk in the `out` directory, another one can come from Eclipse, Ant, Maven or some other tool.

Comment: @CrazyCoder The project has been imported from Eclipse. I have not configured Ant or Maven. **There is no APK in out folder.** How to find and remove Eclipse settings if any?

Comment: Check Android facet settings and the module settings for the output directories configuration.

Comment: Output path in Modules is set to `C:\Users\abc\IdeaProjects\MyApp-1.0.0002\bin\classes`? Should I change it to out folder? Is it the best practice?

Comment: I was referring to [this configuration](http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/7765/20121029021422.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder The configuration you have shown in the image is exactly the same except the option **Include assets in the dependencies into APK**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion of @cracycoder worked

*"Check Android facet settings and the module settings for the output directories configuration. – CrazyCoder Oct 28 at 21:54"*